# Multiple data types in perl object

Tags: perl, object

I'm trying to make an object in perl that contains an array, and two integer scalars.

So far I have:

```
new
{
$class = shift;
$self = [];
$int1 = shift;
$int2 = shift;

bless($self, $class);
}
```

This works for accessing the array with $self->[number]

I want to be able to access int1 and int2 though.  If I put them outside of the constructor, they will change for every instance of the object when I change them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $int1, $int2) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);
    $self->{array} = [];
    $self->{int1} = $int1;
    $self->{int2} = $int2;
    return $self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your integer values to be kept separately from the array, you could write

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %self;
    @self{qw/ array int1 int2 /} = ( [], @_ );
    bless \%self, $class;
}
```

Then you can access the integer scalars as `$self->{int1}` and `$self->{int2}` and the array elements as `$self->{array}[0]`, `$self->{array}[1]` etc. But I hope you realise that you should only do that in the code for the module, and you should write accessor methods for the external software that is using the module